# Glassfish: self signed certificate with two way authentication

Tags: ssl, glassfish, ssl-certificate, glassfish-3

I have an application on a Glassfish server instance. I need to do a two way authentication with certificates. I have a closed group of users, so installing the self signed certificate is not a problem.

The question is, how do you go about doing this entire process? I am using the java based Keystore Explorer instead of the command line tool keytool.

**Before shooting me down, could you please give me a chance to explain my situation better, I know right now the question is a bit hazy, but as the comments come in, I will be able to clarify a bit better!**

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to mutual authentication, please read the following Oracle resource first.
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glien.html#bnbyi

If you still have problems, please provide more details and where you are stuck.